# Problem with Angular (and JHipster): value.toLowerCase is not a function

Tags: angular, filter, pipe, jhipster

With my filter (to filter lines of an entity with a field search), this problem occures : `ERROR TypeError: "value.toLowerCase is not a function"`. I don't know why and how to solve it. The fields of my entity are String except the ID and the problem is still present when I comment the line `searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();` in .ts or if I delete `toLowerCase()` in `return it.toLowerCase().includes(searchText);`

**UPDATE :** The problem occures even with :

```
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: any[], searchText: string): void {
}
```

**So** I realy wonder if there is not a JHipster limitation because it works fine with just Angular as `ng serve`.

**.ts :**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
transform(items: any[], searchText: string): any[] {
    if (!items) {
        return [];
    }
    if (!searchText) {
        return items;
    }

    searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();

    return items.filter(it => {
        return it.toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
    });
}
}
```

**.html :**

```
<div class="table-responsive" *ngIf="laboratories">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><span>ID</span></th>
            <th><span>Name</span></th>
            <th><span>Adress</span></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let laboratory of laboratories | filter:searchText ;trackBy: trackId">
```

Comment: Well to start with, [you should NOT have filtering pipes](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe). Next, simply test your value with `return it && typeof it === 'string' && it.toLowerCase().includes(searchText) || false`.

Comment: @trichetriche No it doesn't solve the problem in both cases.

Comment: No, it's linked to your own code, sorry

Comment: @trichetriche The problem seems to be before or at the beginning of `transform`.

Comment: I gave you the leads on your issues. Without a [mcve], I can't confirm you that. Good luck finding it !

Answer (score 2):

You are iterating on **collections**. When you use ngFor, it iterates over an array. I assume it is an array of laboratories.

This means your objects are laboratories.

In your code, you consider your laboratory to be a string :

```
return items.filter(it => {
  return it.toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
});
```

Maybe you should add some field to filter on ?

```
return items.filter(it => {
  return it.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
});
```

Also, as stated in my comment :

[**Do NOT use filtering pipes**](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe)